# How to use find when there are spaces in the directory names?

Tags: find, filename

I need to find all `.nfo` files in my media directory so I can use `sed` to change some parts. The problem is my folders have spaces in the names.

```
find  /media/media1/HDTV -name  \*.nfo -type f 
media/media1/HDTV/Band of Brothers/Season 1/
…
```

The output file won't found by a `sed` command to change the strings I want.

Comment: For a good read on special character (spaces, &, #, etc.) in filenames, try http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/weirdchars.html

Comment: The problem is not with `find`, it doesn't care about special characters in file names. The problem is with what you do with the `find` output. Post the complete command that you tried, and explain exactly what you want to do with the files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` doesn't care about special characters in file names, but the program that's parsing the output of `find` might. If you're using `xargs`, use the `-print0` option to `find`, and the `-0` option to `xargs`. This tells `find` and `xargs` to use null characters (which cannot appear in file names) as a separator between file names, and `xargs` not to do any other parsing which would mangle file names containing spaces.

```
find /media/media1/HDTV -name '*.nfo' -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/'
```

Another way to invoke a command on many files is to use `find` only.

```
find /media/media1/HDTV -name '*.nfo' -type f -exec sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/' {} +
```

Answer (score -2):

Type normally but put a \ after the word and before the space.

i.e. `cd ~/home/New\ Volume/movies/new\ stuff`

Comment: I need some option to give me this :
find option:
media/media1/HDTV/Band\ of\ Brothers/Season\ 1/...