# Piping find -name to xargs results in filenames with spaces not being passed to the command

Tags: command-line, find, rm, xargs

Normally to remove files with spaces in their filename you would have to run:

```
$ rm "file name"
```

but if I want to remove multiple files, e.g.:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" | xargs rm
```

This will not delete files with spaces in them.

Comment: Complete guess here: does `find -name "*\ *.txt" | xargs rm` work for two word files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use find when there are spaces in the directory names?](http://askubuntu.com/q/148531/309110)  See also [how to avoid space in filename?](http://askubuntu.com/q/250874/309110) and [Problem with spaces in file names](http://askubuntu.com/q/621007/309110).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can tell `find` and `xargs` to both use null terminators

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

or (simpler) use the built-in `-delete` action of `find`

```
find . -name "*.txt" -delete
```

or (thanks @kos)

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} +
```

either of which should respect the system's `ARG_MAX` limit without the need for `xargs`.

Comment: Can't upvote it twice tough :) since you mentioned `ARG_MAX` I'll also mention that `find . -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} \;` would be a "safe shot"

Comment: Thus sayeth the master: always remember xargs -0.

Comment: Super important point: `-print0` must be the last option (or at least after `-name "*.txt"`) otherwise this will hit files *no longer limited to `*.txt`*...

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, if you used something other than find, you can use tr to replace the newlines with null bytes.

Eg. the following one liner deletes the 10 last modified files in a directory, even if they have spaces in their names.

`ls -tp | grep -v / | head -n  10 | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 rm`

Answer (score 1):

The xargs command uses tabs, spaces, and new lines as delimiters by default. You can tell it to only use newline characters ('\n') with the -d option:

`find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -d '\n' rm`

[Source answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/how-can-i-make-xargs-handle-filenames-that-contain-spaces).